# Corrupt PostFix Installv

Tags: server, 14.04, postfix, mail

I accidently removed some files that postfix needs and now it will not install or uninstall
have tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge postfix
sudo apt-get remove postfix
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install postfix
sudo apt-get autoremove postfix
sudo apt-get remore --auto-remove postfix
```

no matter what i do i always recieve the following error:

```
root@GitLab:/# sudo apt-get remove postfix
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  postfix
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 3,361 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 99428 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing postfix (2.11.0-1) ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/postfix not found.
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
/var/lib/dpkg/info/postfix.postinst: 13: .: Can't open /usr/share/postfix/postinst.functions
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

EDIT:
Followed this guide and it was fixed:
http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/

Comment: Please add in the important parts from that site as an answer and accept it. Like this the system will kick this question to the frontpage at random intervals.